# SlidingDrawer rearanges the main layout when opened

Tags: android, animation, layout, slidingdrawer

I have a small animation in my app, that in the end of it changes the location parameters of a ListView i.e. it comes a bit lower than when it started (It starts as full screen and after a button press, its sliding down a little to reveal something beneath it, on the top of the screen). By pressing on the list I can see that its parameters realy changed and its location really changed. Now, if the SlidingDrawer is getting opened at that point, the layout gets rearranged and the list is back to full screen.  Why is that?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.softtechnics.mobuynet"
android:id="@+id/coupon_list_layout"
style="@style/FillParent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/filter_tab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/action_bar"
    layout="@layout/filter" />

<com.softtechnics.mobuynet.gui.components.ListArr
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/action_bar">

</com.softtechnics.mobuynet.gui.components.ListArr>

<com.softtechnics.mobuynet.gui.components.ActionBar
    android:id="@+id/action_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    style="@style/WrapContent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<com.softtechnics.mobuynet.gui.components.Footer
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="113dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

`Footer` is my SlidingDrawer.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You have to change listview properties when the animation ends. Also you should remember actual state of this view and update it in onResume method.

Comment: the animation of the list view is allright. I do change the properties. but after it, if the user opens the drawer then the listView is poping back.  if i will not open the drawer then all is ok.

Comment: Could you paste more code ? Then probably I will be able to find the bug